# Render2 not working in Angular basic project

Tags: css, angular, angular-renderer2, servicemanager

I have an angular application angular-tour-of-heroes with the following structure:

```
src
   ->app
         ->your-component
                  ->your-component.component.html
                  ->your-component.component.less
                  ->your-component.component.ts
                  ->default.less
                  ->custom.less
         ->app.component.html
         ->app.component.ts
         ->app.module.ts
         ->app-routing.module.ts
         ->style-manager.service.ts
```

Now I will share the files:

**app.component.html**

```
<app-your-component></app-your-component>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
// src/app/app.module.ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { YourComponent } from './your-component/your-component.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    YourComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**angular.json**

```
{
"styles": [
"src/styles.less",
"src/app/your-component/default.less",
"src/app/your-component/custom.less"]
}
```

**style-manager.service.ts**

```
// src/app/common_modules/common_services/style-manager.service.ts
import { Injectable, Renderer2, RendererFactory2 } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StyleManagerService {
  private renderer: Renderer2;
  private addedStylesheets: HTMLLinkElement[] = [];
  constructor(rendererFactory: RendererFactory2) {
    this.renderer = rendererFactory.createRenderer(null, null);
  }
  addStylesheets(links: string[]) {
    links.forEach(link => {
      const styleLink = this.renderer.createElement('link');
      this.renderer.setAttribute(styleLink, 'rel', 'stylesheet');
      this.renderer.setAttribute(styleLink, 'type', 'text/css');
      this.renderer.setAttribute(styleLink, 'href', 'custom.less');
      this.renderer.setAttribute(styleLink, 'app-dynamic-style', 'true');
      this.renderer.appendChild(document.head, styleLink);
      this.addedStylesheets.push(styleLink);
    });
  }
  removeStylesheets() {
    // Remove all dynamically added style elements
    this.addedStylesheets.forEach(link => {
      this.renderer.removeChild(document.head, link);
    });
    this.addedStylesheets = [];
  }
}
```

**your-component.component.ts**

```
// src/app/your-component/your-component.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { StyleManagerService } from '../style-manager.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  templateUrl: './your-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./default.less'] // Use default styles by default
})
export class YourComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  constructor(private styleManager: StyleManagerService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    // Some condition to determine which Less file to load
    const condition = true; // Change this condition as needed
    if (condition) {
      // Load custom Less file
      this.styleManager.addStylesheets(['./your-component/custom.less']);
    }
  }
ngOnDestroy() {
    // Remove dynamically added stylesheets when the component is destroyed
    this.styleManager.removeStylesheets();
  }
}
```

**your-component.html**
`<p>your-component works!</p>`

**default.less**

```
p{
    color: aqua;
}
```

**custom.less**

```
p{
    color: yellow;
}
```

I tried the above code and post that when I do ng serve I am getting 404 error for the custom.less file.
Can someone help me as to what and where am I doing wrong

Comment: to inject renderer2, it's like another "service", you not declare outside else in constructor: `constructor(private renderer: Renderer2)`.

Comment: Stylesheets are compiled out and bundled with its component. However I think you can update your `tsconfig.json` somehow by adding it to the `"files"` section.

Answer (score 0):

You can place your css files in the assets folder and then the code will work fine, please find below a working example!

html

```
<select [(ngModel)]="style" (ngModelChange)="setStyleSheet()">
  <option [value]="'../assets/qwerty.css'">qwerty</option>
  <option [value]="'../assets/custom.css'">custom</option>
  <option [value]="'../assets/zxcv.css'">zxcv</option>
</select>
<p class="test">your-component works!</p>
```

ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { StyleManagerService } from '../style-manager.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  templateUrl: './your-component.component.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule],
  styleUrls: ['../assets/default.css'], // Use default styles by default
})
export class YourComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  style = '../assets/default.css';
  constructor(private styleManager: StyleManagerService) {}
  ngOnInit() {}

  setStyleSheet() {
    if (this.style) {
      // Load custom Less file
      this.styleManager.addStylesheets([this.style]);
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // Remove dynamically added stylesheets when the component is destroyed
    this.styleManager.removeStylesheets();
  }
}
```

service

```
// src/app/common_modules/common_services/style-manager.service.ts
import { Injectable, Renderer2, RendererFactory2 } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class StyleManagerService {
  private renderer: Renderer2;
  private addedStylesheets: HTMLLinkElement[] = [];
  constructor(rendererFactory: RendererFactory2) {
    this.renderer = rendererFactory.createRenderer(null, null);
  }
  addStylesheets(links: string[]) {
    links.forEach((link) => {
      if (this.addStylesheets.length) {
        this.addedStylesheets.forEach((link: any) => {
          this.renderer.removeChild(document.head, link);
        });
        this.addedStylesheets = [];
      }
      const styleLink = this.renderer.createElement('link');
      this.renderer.setAttribute(styleLink, 'rel', 'stylesheet');
      this.renderer.setAttribute(styleLink, 'type', 'text/css');
      this.renderer.setAttribute(styleLink, 'href', link);
      this.renderer.setAttribute(styleLink, 'app-dynamic-style', 'true');
      this.renderer.appendChild(document.head, styleLink);
      this.addedStylesheets.push(styleLink);
    });
  }
  removeStylesheets() {
    // Remove all dynamically added style elements
    this.addedStylesheets.forEach((link) => {
      this.renderer.removeChild(document.head, link);
    });
    this.addedStylesheets = [];
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-xhpv3y?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fyour-component%2Fyour-component.component.ts,src%2Fyour-component%2Fyour-component.component.html,src%2Fstyle-manager.service.ts,src%2Fassets%2Fdefault.css,src%2Fassets%2Fzxcv.css&title=Angular%20Starter)